# Weird jQuery Ajax Issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, apache

I'm getting a weird ajax issue... well... not an issue, but you'll see/hear/read

Here's the code I'm using to pull in a page, you can see that I am using 'POST' to pull it in.

```
// Load page inner
function LoadPageInner($url, $cont){
var $loading = '<div class="pageLoader">Loading...<br /><img src="/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading..." height="11" width="16" /></div>';
var $container = jQuery($cont);
var $t = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
var options = {
        url: $url,
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function(){
                $container.slideUp('fast', function(){
                    $container.slideDown('fast').html($loading);    
                });
            },
        success: function(data, status, jqXhr){
            $container.slideUp('fast', function(){
                $container.slideDown('fast').html(data);    
            });
        },
        error: function(jqXhr, status, error){
            $container.slideUp('fast', function(){
                $container.slideDown('fast').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-4x pull-left"></i><p><strong>Danger Will Robinson!</strong><br />There was an issue pulling in this page. Our support team has been notified, please check back later.</p></div>');    
            });
        }
    };
jQuery.ajax(options);
}
```

And to use it, my links have a class called `is-ajax`, and are fired off in the `window` load as such:

```
// Internal site links
var $a = $('a.is-ajax');
$a.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    LoadPageInner($this.attr('href'), $this.attr('data-where'))
});
```

Now, I'm watching firebug, and the `POST` happens to the page I am trying to pull in, but attached to it is a `301 Permanantly Moved` header, and then right under it is a `GET` to the same page
[image]

How can I ensure that this does not happen, or how do I fix it?

Comment: I don't think this is anything to do with your front end code. It seems like the server is redirecting your POST request since it maybe doesn't accept POST requests to that route?

Comment: Your server code is rewriting the request to add the trailing `/`. Check your Apache rewrite rules/ PHP code.

Comment: i did.  initially .htaccess had rewrite rules, but I removed them, and restarted apache...  issue still occurs

Comment: even restarting the server has made no difference...

Comment: Is the problem solely that you're seeing a redirect? If `/views/clients/` returns the data you want then just append a `/` to the url when you call the function.

Comment: If it's not your `.htaccess`, then try what @Matt suggested - check the routing in your PHP code. What framework/routing package are you using?

Comment: no framework.  No routing package

Comment: If you run that URL that you try to POST to in your browser, do you get the desired results that you are expecting in your AJAX request?

Comment: no.  the `/` is always getting appended.  I have no re-writing in my `.htaccess` though...  should I pull the `Options FollowSymLinks` of my site config?

Comment: it doesn't do this double post/get thing if I add /index.php to the end of the url...

Comment: Keep in mind that the it was a 301 rewrite rule which is permanent.
If you're trying to run this script from another computer which never visited the website (wasn't affected by the rewrite rule) it should work. Is it?

Comment: no it's not.  I've gone so far as restarting the server, restarting apache, fully clearing caches on all machines invloved, etc...   still adds the `/`

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, so here goes:

I had a similar issue (had an `.htaccess` redirect, which was removed, but was still getting redirects) and it was the browser's cache. Try clearing it and see if that happens.

Good luck!

Comment: no it's not. I've gone so far as restarting the server, restarting apache, fully clearing caches on all machines invloved, etc... still adds the / –  o7th Web Design 3 hours ago

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to try what @Alexandre Reiff Janini said, if that doesn't work try a different browser, depending on the brand they can be very aggressive in caching the routing.

I noticed your using firebug, there is a toolbar ( for mozilla ) called the web developers tool bar that has an option to disable DNS cache in it that sometimes has worked for me when editing htaccess files.

EDIT: Cant add comments so I'll do an edit,

You might have more then one .htaccess file, you should plant a rule in the one you think is the proper one and see if it indeed is the correct file.  Then you will know for sure that it is not .htaccess,

The only other thing I can think of is an  directive in httpd.conf, see this question for more info [htaccess-limt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081747/htaccess-order-allow-deny-deny-from-all-confused) this is for htaccess but I believe you can do something similar in the Apache config file

Comment: no it's not. I've gone so far as restarting the server, restarting apache, fully clearing caches on all machines invloved, etc... still adds the / –  o7th Web Design 3 hours ago